# I am trying to push heroku master and I get: Build timed out while waiting to start

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying to push my heroku, to put my project online and to execute: git push heroku master

I get:

```
Enumerating objects: 29, done.
Counting objects: 100% (29/29), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 9.13 KiB | 1.83 MiB/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:  !
remote:  !   Build timed out while waiting to start.
remote:  !
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to arthuro-gomez-web-api.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/arthuro-gomez-web-api.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/arthuro-gomez-web-api.git'
```

Try to do the push with this

```
git fetch
git merge  # or git rebase
git push
```

And I got the same error, if someone can help me or indicate a solution? I have seen some questions here in SO, but they did not work for me, I have restarted the IDE and I have also waited 15 min. Would appreciate your help

Comment: There is a problem on the heroku side: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2081

Comment: Oh, I just saw, thanks so much for taking the time, I didn't know I could see that information: D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a problem on Heroku's side for me as well.

https://status.heroku.com/

[image]